# Silverlight 3 breakpoints not hit when launching external program

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-3.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, Silverlight 3 and IE 6 (don't ask).

I'm trying to launch and debug the application with F5, but the debugger says my breakpoints won't be hit because the symbols aren't loaded.

My default browser is actually Firefox, but I am setting the Start Action of the project to specifically launch IE and point it at the correct URL, so that I can debug in IE but use Firefox for normal web stuff.

If I launch the process this way without attaching the debugger, then attach after it has launched, everything is fine. If I make IE my default browser, set the Start Action to "Current Page", then everything is fine.

With IE as the default browser, but the Start Action set to "Start external program" and pointing it to IE, the problem appears again. So it appears that the problem is that launching an external program with the debugger attached isn't working for me, regardless of what is the default browser.

I've tried this with the actual app as well as a brand new test project and both behave the same.

Any hints on how to get this working? Or am I doomed to making IE6 my default browser, setting Current Page as the Start Action, and copy/pasting all links into Firefox instead of clicking them? :(

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before while troubleshooting odd issues in cross-browser support.  What you can do is set create a visual studio macro to

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90

Public Module AutoAttachMacro

   Sub StartDebugging()            
      Dim Projs As Array
      Dim Proj As Project
      Projs = DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects()
      If (Projs.Length > 0) Then
         Proj = Projs.GetValue(0)
         Dim Prop As EnvDTE.Property
         Prop = DTE.Solution.Properties.Item("StartupProject")
         Dim PrevStartup As Object
         PrevStartup = Prop.Value
         Prop.Value = Proj.Name
         DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.StartWithoutDebugging")
         Prop.Value = PrevStartup
      End If

      ' Lookup ProcessId '

      For Each process AS EnvDTE.Process In DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses
         If process.ProcessID = processId Then
            process.Attach()
            DTE.Debugger.CurrentProcess = process
         End If
      Next process       

End Module
```

Thanks btw to the following question/answers for the help:
[How to start a single project without debugging in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356565/how-to-start-a-single-project-without-debugging-in-visual-studio)