# Start without debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start a single project without debugging in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356565/how-to-start-a-single-project-without-debugging-in-visual-studio)

In Visual Studio 2010, is there any way to start a **non-StartUp** Project **without debugging**?

Of course I mean *without* changing the solution settings (i.e. assume there **is** a StartUp project, which is the one I want to start 90% of the time)

I'll take a macro if someone knows how to write it.

Comment: Hope i deleted my answer in time. I missed the "without debugging" clause in your question. ;-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it important that the other one start without debugging?

Comment: Vote here (http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2267061-add-a-start-without-debugging-option-for-individua)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356565/how-to-start-a-single-project-without-debugging-in-visual-studio/1356970#1356970) for a solution.** Mahin provides a macro there to do it. It's not perfect, but it works if you can tolerate the minor issues. Alex Dresko provides an [alternate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356565/how-to-start-a-single-project-without-debugging-in-visual-studio/2059223#2059223), but it doesn't compile your application automatically.

Mahin suggests assigning the macro to a keyboard shortcut, but you can also add it to the project right-click menu with the following steps:

1. Go to the `Tools -> Customize...` menu.
2. Go to the `Commands` tab.
3. Choose the `Context menu` radio button.
4. Choose `Project and Solution Context Menus | Project | Debug` from the drop-down menu, or whatever other menu you want to add it to.
5. Click the `Add Command...` button.
6. Navigate to the `Macros` category and select your custom macro.
7. Click `OK` and then `Close`.

That's what I do.

Comment: I like this first one. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I like the second because it doesn't try to switch the startup project as in the first one (which does not work if you are already debugging)

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the project and select "Open Folder in Windows Explorer".  Simply double-click the EXE.  You can click the Show All Files icon in the Solution Explorer window to navigate to the build directory in VS instead of Explorer.

Comment: I currently have a desktop shortcut, but I'd like to do it from VS, preferrably preserving the compilations semantics that I have with *Right click -> Debug -> Start new instance"* without having to remember to compile manually first.