# How to configure the command line that Visual Studio executes for starting console applications?

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, console-application

When using Visual Studio to execute the command "**Start without debugging**" on a console application, I can see with Process Monitor, that Visual Studio actually executes something like:

> "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c ""C:\MyProject\MyApp.exe"  & **pause**"

I.e. it appends a "[& pause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MS-DOS_commands#PAUSE)" at the end. This is intentionally so that when my application exits, it prints

> Press any key to continue . . .

and thus prevents the console window to be closed automatically.

While I understand the intention, I have one project where I do *not* want the window to stay open.

I've searched through SO and also did a naive full-text search through all files in "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" for "pause", yet did not find any relevant references.

I strongly assume that this is an option I can configure somewhere (even if deep inside some configuration file, or a registry).

**My question is:**

How to configure the command line that is being executed when clicking "Start without debugging"?

Answer (score 1):

`pause` is a dos command. When the command prompt executes such a line it waits for a user's key press.

I don't think that "Start without debugging" is configurable. Instead you have other options like:

- [Writing your own macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356970/145682)
- You can create an external command via the Tools > [External Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/07/24/using-external-tools-vstiptool0059.aspx) dialog. Put the same stuff you've mentioned in your post without the `pause` part.