# Update Service Reference from within solution

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution that has a WCF service project, and a client project.  I can successfully add the service reference by discovering the service within the solution. However, after adding the service reference and making changes, I am unable to update the service reference.  I know it's because the service isn't actively running/being debugged.  In order to update the service reference I have to delete it, then add it back again since you can't update the service reference while debugging.  I just updated to VS 2015 and was hoping that a solution had been added but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Am I missing something or is that just how it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run it without debug: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> and then update the reference.   Not being familiar with your project, you may need to host it in IIS or self host in a console app or something to do this.

Comment: Absolutely perfect!  Stack Overflow to the rescue!  Now one quick question: I have my default startup program as the client.  In order for this to work I have to change the service as the default startup, then run without debug.  Is there any way to add the "Run without debug" to the right click menu on the service project?  Or should I create a new question for this?

Comment: Nevermind, did a quick search and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356565/how-to-start-a-single-project-without-debugging-in-visual-studio/2059223#2059223.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of off the top of my head.  Alternatively you could just create a shortcut to your compiled output assembly and run it outside of visual studio all together.

Answer (score 3):

If you do run the WCF in debug, once it loads, just go to your debug menu in VS and click "Detach All." Then update your service reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your application published on local IIS, you must change the server on your Web Application Project.
Go to `Your Project > properties > Web > web Servers` and select `External Host` on the Combobox. Set the project URL to the same as your local IIS is running your Application. Try Update your reference again.